# Is it prohibited to use Spotify iOS SDK if your app uses navigation?

Tags: ios, spotify

I'd like to have a feature in my iOS app to display the control for Spotify `play/stop`, `previous song` and `next song`. My app shows some statistics regarding your car. But it can also be used to navigate to the desired location.

The [Spotify iOS SDK page](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/) says:

> The iOS SDK **is explicitly prohibited from use for in-car apps**, alarm clock apps, ring-tone apps, voice-assistants, broadcast aka “listen together” apps, and to create offline experiences for wearable or other devices.

What does the term "in-car app" mean?

Does anyone know about some features that make your app to fit in that category?

Is it because of the "navigation feature" that my app can't use the Spotify SDK?

Thank you!

Comment: The only way to get a definitive answer is if you contact spotify directly and state clearly what you app does and does not do.

Comment: True, but I couldn't find a way to contact them directly. They say that SO is the place to post questions with tag `Spotify`. Additionally, at the bottom there is a comment section with 2 year old posts only, so I'm not optimistic about it.

Comment: Contact them via Facebook, Twitter or using the [Contact Form](https://support.spotify.com/us/contact-spotify-support/) (Select `Tecnical Issues` > `Other` > `I still need help`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've follow @nathan's comment and contacted Spotify directly using the [Contact Form](https://support.spotify.com/us/contact-spotify-support/) (Select `Tecnical Issues` > `Other` > `I still need help`) and was able to get more clarification. Found out that just by having navigation in the app doesn't mean you can't use their SDK. For reference or comparison; also Waze app has Spotify integration.